# In PHP, is it possible to upload files to the server?

Tags: php, xampp, localhost

In PHP, is it possible to upload files to the server? If so, then how can I create an upload form and insert the files to a specific page? Any extension images: .jpeg .gif or files: .txt .pdf etc. I am using XAMPP (localhost to view my website).

I have tried many tutorials, but there are lot of errors.

This is this HTML file:

```
<form action="fileupload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<label for="file">Filename:</label>
<input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

And here is the PHP script:

```
if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0)
{
    echo "Error: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br />";
}
else
{
    echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
    echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
    echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
    echo "Stored in: " . $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
}
```

The result is shown like this:

> Upload: (file here)
>      Type: image/jpeg
>      Size: 757.521484375 Kb
>      Stored in: (temp file in C:)

But whenever I find my file in the tmp folder. It's nowhere to be found.

Comment: have you tried your self first ? if yes then show us the problem

Comment: What Harshal meant to say was http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp

Comment: http://www.w3fools.com/

Comment: If you leave the file in the temp folder, it will be automatically deleted when the script terminates; it's up to your code to [move_uploaded_file()](http://www.php.net/function.move-uploaded-file) to a permanent folder on your system

Answer (score 0):

```
    function getExtension($str)
    {
        $i = strrpos($str,".");
        if (!$i)
        {
            return "";
        }
        $l = strlen($str) - $i;
        $ext = substr($str,$i+1,$l);
        return $ext;
    }

    $extension = getExtension($filename);
    $extension = strtolower($extension);
    if($extension=="jpg" || $extension=="jpeg" || $extension=="gif" || $extension=="txt" || $extension=="pdf" ){

  echo "Upload: " . $_FILES["file"]["name"] . "<br />";
  echo "Type: " . $_FILES["file"]["type"] . "<br />";
  echo "Size: " . ($_FILES["file"]["size"] / 1024) . " Kb<br />";
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" .date("d_m_h_i_s"). $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    }
```

The getExtension function helps to get the extension of the file. The files will be uploaded to the upload folder.